# How to add two value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am preparing a demo of add function where user enter two values in input field and result will be display on third field

But I am not able to show that result

Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-smoke-ewkbd

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      Add Demo
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      {state.map(({ type, label, name }) => {
        if (type === "text") {
          return (
            <div>
              <label>{label}</label>
              <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} name={name} />
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

When I entered `2` in first field and `2` in second field .Expected output will be `4` in result field

Comment: use state to get the desired result.

Comment: You are just prinitng value. Use state and manage this value using useState

Comment: I need to set the value in `result` field

Comment: Here is a solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-snowflake-d0ffj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I agree with your idea of using State, but better use form value where you can freely update your values.
2. If you need calculation, you can use `number` type rather than `text`
3. Use `setForm` for update value
4. Provide value with form values and show result with combination of first and second.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-violet-tv0vw